# what happen at background when you click inside a textbox?

Tags: windows, mfc

Inside a MFC dialog, I have 2 overlapping rows of text boxes (what user can see is only one row). when I clicked a button, i shifted down the row at bottom, so now user can see both rows.

The problem is if I have some data loaded in DoDataExchange() for the text boxes, I wouldn't be able to see them showing when the dialog boots up. But when I click inside the text box, the data shows.

I want to know what exactly happen when I clicked a UI? What drawing functions are invoked at backgrounds? So I can fix my problem.

Thank you.
ZQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is drawn when you click, maybe you are seeing an Invalidate() being triggered for some reason that redraws the text boxes. Or maybe the parent control (dialog, I assume) doesn't have WS_CLIPCHILDREN set, or some other funny things are happening with the WS_CLIPXXX flags (they're somewhat of a black art).

More to the point, use Spy++ to check what 'happens' when you click - i.e. the messages that are posted at each point in time.

Comment: Thank you, I will try using spy++. Anyway, I changed strategy now. It's better just draw those textboxes when needed at correct position.